# How to call in tag manager data after user OAUTH2 authorization is complete (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, api, authentication, tags

I've been at this all day trying to figure out how to do an XMLHTTP request after authorization but just can't for the life of me figure it out.

So far I've got the code below which authorizes the user.

```
    var OAUTHURL    =   'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?';
    var VALIDURL    =   'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?
    access_token=';
    var SCOPE       =   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile 
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email';
    var CLIENTID    =   'NOT SHOWING FOR SECURITY REASONS';
    var REDIRECT    =   'NOT SHOWING FOR SECURITY REASONS'
    var LOGOUT      =   'http://accounts.google.com/Logout';
    var TYPE        =   'token';
    var _url        =   OAUTHURL + 'scope=' + SCOPE + '&client_id=' + CLIENTID + '&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT + '&response_type=' + TYPE;
    var acToken;
    var tokenType;
    var expiresIn;
    var user;
    var loggedIn    =   false;

    function login() {
        var win         =   window.open(_url, "windowname1", 'width=800, height=600'); 

        var pollTimer   =   window.setInterval(function() { 
            try {
                console.log(win.document.URL);
                if (win.document.URL.indexOf(REDIRECT) != -1) {
                    window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                    var url =   win.document.URL;
                    acToken =   gup(url, 'access_token');
                    tokenType = gup(url, 'token_type');
                    expiresIn = gup(url, 'expires_in');
                    win.close();

                    validateToken(acToken);
                }
            } catch(e) {
            }
        }, 500);
    }

    function validateToken(token) {
        $.ajax({
            url: VALIDURL + token,
            data: null,
            success: function(responseText){  
                getUserInfo();
                loggedIn = true;
                $('#loginText').hide();
                $('#logoutText').show();
            },  
            dataType: "jsonp"  


    });
    }

    function getUserInfo() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=' + acToken,
            data: null,
            success: function(resp) {
                user    =   resp;
                console.log(user);
                $('#uName').text('Welcome ' + user.name);
                $('#imgHolder').attr('src', user.picture);
            },
            dataType: "jsonp"
        });
    }

    //credits: http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html
    function gup(url, name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
        var regexS = "[\\#&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
        var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
        var results = regex.exec( url );
        if( results == null )
            return "";
        else
            return results[1];
    }

    function startLogoutPolling() {
        $('#loginText').show();
        $('#logoutText').hide();
        loggedIn = false;
        $('#uName').text('Welcome ');
        $('#imgHolder').attr('src', 'none.jpg');
    }
```

The code works fine as far as the login goes. It's after logging in that I don't know what to do. I've tried multiple ideas and have gotten nowhere. Any ideas on how I can call tags from tag manager in "readonly" mode after this login?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I just decided to try using the JavaScript web app method and was able to get this working. If you run into the same issue using the ajax version here is the documentation! Make sure to select the JavaScript tab or you can try the oAuth2.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent